# How can I stop game when I run a animation windows?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1.9
How can I stop  game when I run a animation windows?
means:
I click on menu button so run  a animation windows and I want stop game when this animation(run windows menu ) is running

I used timescale=0 so I see stop animation menu also , what do I do ?

Comment: Stop your other scripts e.g. via `someScriptReference.enabled = false;`. The problem with the timescale is that obviously it also affects everything depending on the time (such as animations)

Comment: This is surely about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].